# How to create stack views dynamical in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistackview

Hi i developed a program for four stack view to add another stack in same view i need to another sub view, is there any other way for adding subview using for loop, i am new to swift language and learning, please need help

How to keep all stack views in for loop so that i can add n number stack views

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your code with your loop and attempt at creating a dynamic stack view?

Comment: @tebs1200 i created 4 horizontal views, but in future i may want to create 10 horizontal views, so i am asking any best way to create this sort of things, sorry once again if you don't understand question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is snippet of code that builds a keypad using UIStackViews...

```
func newPad() {
    keyPadWindow = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 128, y: 224, width: 512, height: 356))
    keyPadWindow.backgroundColor  = UIColor.yellowColor()
    var keyCount = 0
    keyPadSV = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 512, height: 356))
    keyPadSV!.axis = .Vertical
    keyPadSV!.spacing = 0.0
    keyPadSV!.alignment = .Center
    keyPadSV!.distribution = .EqualSpacing
    keyPadSV!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    for var k2s = 0; k2s < 5; k2s++ {
        let keyPadSVB = UIStackView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        keyPadSVB.axis = .Horizontal
        keyPadSVB.spacing = 0.0
        keyPadSVB.alignment = .Center
        keyPadSVB.distribution = .EqualSpacing
        keyPadSVB.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        for var k4s = 0; k4s < 4; k4s++ {
            let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
            button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            button.tag =  keyCount
            let blah = "x" + String(keyCount)
            let blahIMAGE = UIImage(named: blah)
            button.setImage(blahIMAGE, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: "keyPadPress:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            keyPadSVB.addArrangedSubview(button)
            keyCount++
        }
        keyPadSV.addArrangedSubview(keyPadSVB)
    }
    keyPadWindow.addSubview(keyPadSV)
    self.view.addSubview(keyPadWindow)
}
```

It relies on you having 16 images for the keys to be displayed.

Comment: is there a missing "let" or "var" where you create the first UIStackView?

Comment: I looking at it, no time to test it, but nothing missing as far as i can see. Why you ask? Are you getting an error suggesting something missing?